# Compile wkhtmltopdf with a "patched Qt" in 2021

Tags: qt, wkhtmltopdf

Table of contents broke in `wkhtmltopdf-0.12.5`, and certain tables are broken in `wkhtmltopdf-0.12.6` for me. I'd like to apply this patch to `wkhtmltopdf-0.12.5` : https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/pull/3962, and rebuild it myself, but it doesn't appear so straightforward as there's a lot of mention of a "patched version of Qt," but no way to access these patches or the patched source tree that I can find.

So does anyone out there know how, in 2021, to compile **wkhtmltopdf** for Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The patched QT is in the [QT submodule of WKHTMLTOPDF](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/qt), so if you clone the main repo with *git clone --recurse-submodules* you should get everything you need to build. It's been a few years since I've built it, but there haven't been many changes since then.